# svn call from python not working on ubuntu box

Tags: django, svn, ubuntu, ssh

I have a python script in my django project that grabs information from an 'svn log' call and displays it on a page.

Something like:

```
cmd = 'svn log svn://(blahblahblah)'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

This call works locally in my Windows environment, but when deployed to our ubuntu instance, it doesn't seem to return anything.

When I ssh onto the box, I am able to do 'svn log' just fine from the command line, not sure if my ssh session uses different credentials than what django is running as. I also tried specifying --username and --password in my 'svn log' call, but this actually prompts me for a username and password - not sure why that is.

Comment: Two questions - what user is your django process running as (you're asking part of it in your question).  Second, are you sure your directories are fully qualified and your path's have the slash in the correct orientation.

Comment: I don't know how to check what user the django process is running as. The same svn log call works on the server command line as it does locally, so it doesn't seem like the slashes have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using *subprocess*? Maybe you can use *os.system*:

```
import os
cmd = 'svn log svn://(blahblahblah)'
os.system(cmd)
```

Also, take care about *shell=True* because it can be a [security hazard](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).